# Insert into with select query of two tables with default value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-insert

Table1: `INVOICE (CNum, PatID, RefBy)`

```
CNum  |PatID  | RefBy
=======================
101   |201    | Dr.Ram
102   |202    | Dr.John
104   |201    | Dr.Philander
104   |203    | Dr.Smith
105   |204    | Dr.Bashir
106   |201    | Dr.Raj
```

Table2: `PATIENT (PatID, Name)`

```
PatID  | Name
======================
201    | Jay
202    | Robert
203    | Divya
204    | Sarala
205    | Pratheeksha
206    | Tim
```

**Table3** `BASECASE(CaseNumber, Name, CaseTopic, RefBy, TrtDoctor)`

**SQL Query**

```
Insert into BASECAS
  from CHECKUP and PATIENT
  (CaseNumber from PatientID of PATIENT /* all the rows */)
  (Name from Name of PATIENT /*All the rows corresponding to PatientID */)
  (CaseTopic column will have `-` for all rows)
  (MAX(RefBy) from RefBy CHECKUP where PATIENT.PatientID = CHECKUP.PatientID, If the Patient.PatientID does not exist in **Table1 - CHECKUP**, it should return **'-'**)
  (TrtDoctor column will have '-' for all rows)
```

Expected result after the query:

```
CaseNumber | Name       | CaseTopic | RefBy    | TrtDoctor
==========================================================
201        | Jay        | -         | Dr.Ram   | -
202        | Robert     | -         | -        | -
203        | Divya      | -         | Dr.Smith | -
204        | Sarala     | -         | Dr.Bashir| -
205        | Pratheeksha| -         | -        | -
206        | Tim        | -         | -        | -
```

How do I to sort out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Think you can do it just like this:

```
INSERT INTO BASECASE
SELECT pat.PatID, pat.Name, '-', COALESCE(ref.RefBy, '-'), '-' 
FROM PATIENT pat
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT PatID, MAX(RefBy) RefBy FROM INVOICE GROUP BY PatID
) ref ON ref.PatID = pat.PatID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample output data does not seem to correspond with the description: the numbers in `CaseNumber`seem to be the PatID, not the CNum, and also the patient Robert should have a RefBy Dr.John I think?

The table name for table 1 is given as INVOICE first, and then referred to as CHECKUP, I assume the latter is correct.

**Please make sure your description and sample data/output is correct**

In any case, to get the sample output this should work:

```
INSERT BASECASE (CaseNumber, Name, CaseTopic, RefBy, TrtDoctor)
SELECT 
    CaseNumber = p.PatID, 
    p.Name,
    CaseTopic = '-',
    RefBy = ISNULL(RefBy,'-'),
    TrtDoctor = '-'
from PATIENT p 
OUTER APPLY (
             SELECT MAX(RefBy) AS RefBy 
             FROM CHECKUP 
             WHERE p.PatID = PatID
            ) Ref
```